# Where is my Joomla component menu item?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am writing my first Joomla component, on Joomla 3.3.0, following the book [Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development, Third Edition.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782168370)

I am following the author's advice and writing code directly under Jommla's folders, such as `\administrator\components\com_coup`, where `com_coup` is my component for a coupon management system. I have a full folder structure, and at the end of a chapter the author says I should have a certain folder and file structure, and am ready for installation by *Discovery*, Joomla finds my component in `Site` and `Administration`, and installing the admin one seems to go well, but no menu item is inserted into the `Components` menu.

Should I be discovering two components, why is my menu item not inserted. My `coup.xml' file contains the line:

```
<administration>
    <menu img="class:categories">COM_COUP_MENU</menu>
```

and the text item `COM_COUP_MENU` exists in the `language\en-GB\en-GB.com_coup.sys.ini` file.

My `coup.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.0" method="upgrade">
    <name>com_coup</name>
    <author>Brady Kelly</author>
    <creationDate>2014-06-14</creationDate>
    <copyright>(C) Erisia Web Development. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>brady@bradykelly.net</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://thepraxis.co.za/</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>COM_COUP_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
    <install>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
    <uninstall>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </uninstall>
    <files folder="site">
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <administration>
        <menu img="class:categories">COM_COUP_MENU</menu>
        <files folder="admin">
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>access.xml</filename>
            <filename>config.xml</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <filename>coup.php</filename>
            <folder>controllers</folder>
            <folder>helpers</folder>
            <folder>models</folder>
            <folder>sql</folder>
            <folder>tables</folder>
            <folder>views</folder>
        </files>
        <languages folder="admin">
            <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_coup.ini</language>
            <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_coup.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>
    </administration>
</extension>
```

and my `en-GB.com_coup.sys.ini` file is:

```
COM_COUP="Coup"
COM_COUP_XML_DESCRIPTION="The winning voucher and coupon manager!"
COM_COUP_MENU="Voucher Coup"
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be failing in a few different places, the first thing to check is that you have error reporting set to "**Development**" (`Global Configuration—>Server->Server Settings`) and `Debug System` turned on (`Global Configuration—>System->Debug Settings`), you may also want to turn on `Debug Language` (it's just below `Debug System`).

Stepping through process these are the steps that are happening (you don't mention any errors and a silent failure seems unusual).

When `discover()` runs it loads all of the `installer/adapater/`'s found in `/libraries/cms/`, you've said it's a component, so the `component.php` adapter is the relevant one. This loops through the site and admin `/components/` directories looking for each components xml file (i.e. your `coup.xml`). *If there was a problem in your XML file this could cause an error but it would occur before the install step which apparently you can run.*

The fact that your component is found twice might be part of the problem… do you have `coup.xml` in both the site's `/components/com_coup` and `/administrator/components/com_coup`? (Our extensions only have them in the admin side, I'd probably remove the front end one).

The adapters return an array of found items (components, modules, plugins, libraries etc) this is compared to the extensions registered in `#__extensions` and any items that aren't listed are added to the extensions table with a `state` of `-1`. The "Discover" view then displays the list of items found so the user can select one or more of them and "Install" them.

`discover_install()` basically runs a normal install (except the copy files), so it runs any install `SQL` files.

Then it runs `_buildAdminMenus()` to add the Admin menus where it looks to see if the extension already has a menu before over writing it.

Finally any `InstallerScript` file found in the manifest is run.

Each of these stages could throw an error - but you should see an error message of some kind in that case.

I would check:

1. your XML file validates correctly
2. for Language file errors (shown in the Joomla Debug Console, when `Debug Languages` is enabled.
3. check your SQL install files run in a SQL console like [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com) or [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
4. validate your instal script (`php -l /path/to/file.php`)

Adding your **full** XML file and `sys.ini` language file could also help. `ini` language files can be tricky if you haven't been using the `Debug Languages` option.

Comment: I've added those files to the question, and followed all your advice. One thing is that the extension install ends on an empty page `http://localhost/joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=discover`, and inserts an entry into `jos_extensions`. The uninstall leaves an empty `http://localhost/joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=manage` page, but doesn't remove the entry from `jos_extensions`.

My sql files are generated by myPhpAdmin.

Comment: When you say an "empty page" do you mean the browser window is blank… if so, you have a PHP error somewhere. Most likely in your install script.

Comment: Yep, browser is blank, not Joomla content area. I'll double check the script, thanks.